# How to store cookie jar to be used between functions inside class?

Tags: python, cookiestore

I'd like to hear your suggestions on how to effectively store cookies, that are to be used inside a class by other functions. My current code looks like this:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.logged_in      = False
        self.username       = username
        self.password       = password
        opener              = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor())
        urllib2.install_opener(opener)

    def _login(self, username, password):
        if not self.logged_in:
            params = urllib.urlencode({'username': username, 'password': password})
            conn = urllib2.Request('http://somedomain.com/login', params)
            urllib2.urlopen(conn)
            self.logged_in = True

    def _checkLogin(self):
        if not self.logged_in:
            self._login(self.username, self.password)

    def doSomeStuffThatRequireCookies(self):
        self._checkLogin()
        data = urllib2.urlopen(conn).read()
        return data
```

Although above example works, I must build custom Request() if I do NOT want to make request with cookies and I am sure there must be better and more elegant way to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, as jathanism noticed, you are not actually installing the cookie jar.

```
import cookielib
...

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookielib.CookieJar()))
```

Then, urllib2.install_opener(opener) will install the opener globally(!), which you do not need to do. Remove urllib2.install_opener(opener).

For non-cookie requests do this:

You don't need to build the Request object, you can just call urlopen with url and params:

```
params = urllib.urlencode({'username': username, 'password': password})
urllib2.urlopen('http://somedomain.com/login', params)
```

For cookie requests, use the opener object:

```
self.opener.urlopen(url, data)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But I think you forgot to add code snippet under "For non-cookie requests do this" part of your answer.

Comment: This answer was super helpful to me, except for one small issue.  `OpenerDirector` objects do not have a `urlopen` function; the last line of your answer should just be `self.opener.open(url, data)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import cookielib

class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        #self.logged_in      = False
        #self.username       = username
        #self.password       = password
        self.cookiejar      = cookielib.CookieJar()
        opener              = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(self.cookiejar))
        #urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

I commented out the stuff that was already there to highlight what I changed.