# python-requests - can't login

Tags: python, python-requests

trying to scrape some data, but first I need to login. I am trying to use [python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), and here is my code so far :

```
login_url = "https://www.wehelpen.nl/login/"
users_url = "https://www.wehelpen.nl/ik-zoek-hulp/hulpprofielen/"
profile_url = "https://www.wehelpen.nl/profiel/01136/hulpvragen/"

uname = "****"
pword = "****"


def main():
    s = login(uname, pword, login_url)
    page = s.get(users_url)
    print makeUTF8(page.text) # grab html and grep for logged in text to make sure!


def login(uname, pword, url):
    s = requests.session()
    s.get(url, auth=(uname, pword))
    csrftoken = s.cookies['csrftoken']
    login_data = dict(username=uname, password=pword,
                  csrfmiddlewaretoken=csrftoken, next='/')
    s.post(url, data=login_data, headers=dict(Referer=url))
    return s


def makeUTF8(text):
    return text.encode('utf-8')
```

Basically, I need to login at `login_url` with a `POST` request (using a `csrf` token because I get an error otherwise), then using the `session` object passed back from `login()`, I want to check that I am logged in by making a `GET` request to a user page. When I get the return - `page.text` I can then run a `grep` command to check for a certain `href` which tells me if I am logged in or not.

So, thus far I am unable to login and keep a working session object. Can anyone help me? So far, this has been the most tedious python experience of my life.

EDIT. I have searched, searched and searched SO for answers and nothing is working...

Comment: Can you show us the output of the POST request?

Comment: heres the full source if anyone fancies - http://goo.gl/wekFoj

Comment: I was thinking about `response.text`.

Comment: thar she blows - http://pastebin.com/fw3fmHJ4

Comment: as you can see, "<li><a href="/aanmelden/">aanmelden</a>|</li>" (aanmelden = login) is there which means, it is returning an unlogged in page...

Comment: Is the `csrftoken` value from the cookie the right value for the `csrfmiddlewaretoken` or do you need to scrape that from the page response? Also, it looks like you should be using `identification` instead of `username` in your `login_data`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have correct names for dictionary keys. Request libary uses html name of form to find right form. In your case those names are identification and password.

```
login_data = {'identification'=uname,'password'=pswrd...}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of options, but I have had success using `cookielib` instead of trying to "manually" handle the cookies.

```
import urllib2
import cookielib
cookiejar = cookielib.CookieJar()
cookiejar.clear()
urlOpener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookiejar))
# ...etc...
```

Some potentially relevant answers on getting this set up are on SO, including: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5826033/1681480

Comment: no luck there...can't get past this csrf stuff with cookielib.